# Does __attribute__((visibility("default"))) apply to nested structures?

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, visibility

When I write classes in C++ and use the Pimpl idiom, I generally set
the structure up like so:

### Foo.hpp

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();


    void method1();
    void method2();

private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> p;
};
```

### Foo.cpp

```
struct Foo::impl
{
    method1()
    {
        ....
    }
    method2()
    {
        ...
    }

    private_thing()
    {
        ...
    }

}

Foo::Foo():p(make_unique<impl>()){}
Foo::~Foo(){}
void Foo::method1(){ p->method1();}
void Foo::method2(){ p->method2();}
```

I'd like to hide some of the symbols for the implementation, so I
compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` and add
`__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to the `class Foo` definintion, like so:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Foo {...};
```

My question is whether the visibility attribute applies to the methods
of the nested impl struct and makes all members visible or whether
they stay hidden.

Comment: You could easily answer your own question by running a tool such as `objdump`, `nm` or `readelf` on your compiled binary and listing exported symbols.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. It's rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the code with "nm -CD foo.so", we can see that the nested struct is in fact visible:

```
0000000000201048 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201048 D _edata
0000000000201050 B _end
00000000000009cc T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000780 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U operator delete(void*)
000000000000099c W Foo::impl::method1()
00000000000009a8 W Foo::impl::method2()
00000000000009b4 W Foo::impl::impl()
00000000000009b4 W Foo::impl::impl()
0000000000000960 T Foo::method1()
000000000000097e T Foo::method2()
0000000000000910 T Foo::Foo()
0000000000000910 T Foo::Foo()
0000000000000942 T Foo::~Foo()
0000000000000942 T Foo::~Foo()
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
```

However, declaring `Foo::impl` as a non-nested struct `Foo_impl`, we then get the following:

```
0000000000201030 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201030 D _edata
0000000000201038 B _end
000000000000088c T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000668 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U operator delete(void*)
0000000000000820 T Foo::method1()
000000000000083e T Foo::method2()
00000000000007d0 T Foo::Foo()
00000000000007d0 T Foo::Foo()
0000000000000802 T Foo::~Foo()
0000000000000802 T Foo::~Foo()
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
```

so it appears that yes, the visibility specifier does in fact propogate to nested structures.